# Java data streaming class selection

Tags: java, file-io

There are too many types of data streaming classes in the Java API. I would like to use a simple binary reading class that would allow for streaming a file locally or over a network.

I would also like to be able to read specific types of data, such as integer, double, etc. without constructing that data from bytes (that would make horribly unreadable code). Is there a class that exists to fit this need already? Or would I be better off extending an existing class?

Please bear in mind that I am initially going to read local files and extend its capability to read files over a network at a later time, hopefully with minimal code changes.

Thanks

Comment: If you're not aware of the functionality of all the stream-based classes in Java, do you think it's really appropriate to assert that there are too many? Perhaps you meant: "I'm confused by all the stream-based classes in the Java API" which would be rather less argumentative.

Comment: There are too many. If there's so many as to confuse me, there are more than are necessary, since many languages only require one. Java branches off with many specific subtypes - for what I assume is readability and simplification of code - but it complicates the development process by selection. Too many for what is needed. Just my opinion - not gospel. After all, if it's necessary for me to research and know which type to use for a specific situation, that's just ridiculous. In another language, they have one binary reading construct. Maybe less generalized but is more fundamental

Comment: Certainly just opinion, and one which I disagree with. By extension, perhaps there should actually just be *one* class - not just for IO, but for *everything*? Then you'd never have to select anything. Clearly that's ridiculous - it makes sense to pick the right class for what you want to represent... and that's true for IO as well. Perhaps you'll find that when you understand the types available a bit better, you'll find your code clearer due to the split...

Comment: (I note that the platforms which only have one IO construct are often the same ones that don't clearly distinguish between binary data and text data, etc, leading to general confusion as soon as you want to be *totally* clear about what you're working with. Again, a flaw IMO - even if it may *seem* to make things simpler to start with.)

Comment: That's what I'd consider C programming to be. Awesome language. Certainly not OOP, but it's so fundamental, I can memorize the entire standard API. Not trying to argue; I respect your opinion. I just hate it when things that are so fundamental are made so complex.

Comment: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. I don't think the Java API is perfect (and I *usually* find the .NET one more pleasant, where at least the abstract `Stream` class is both "in" and "out") but I *do* approve of the splitting of functionality from "a stream" to "a stream working with files" to "a stream working with sockets" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DataInputStream wrapping a BufferedInputStream wrapping a FileInputStream to read. Use a DataoutputStream wrapping a BufferedOutputStream wrapping the socket's output stream to write.

Each has its responsibilities:

- The file and socket streams are used to read/write data from/to socket
- The buffered streams avoid having too many native calls by buffering the input/output and thus enhancing the performance of the app
- The Data streams allow manipulating bytes, ints, and other types instead of raw bytes.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down for me :) I'd +1 you but I don't have that ability, apparently

Answer (score 1):

[`DataInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and [`DataOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) perhaps? (They wrap an existing `InputStream` or `OutputStream`, which is how you can get them to work locally or over a network etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are character stream readers and binary stream reader classes available in Java. The InputStream classes are the binary readers which can be used. Use the DataInputStream to read datatypes. Whether you read from file or from over the network you still will have the InputStream availble to read from.